# Bootstrap mobile navbar not showing correctly

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile

Navbar is working correctly on desktop, but on the phone it looks like this:

[image]

How can I disable the menu on mobile version or what is the best way to fix it?

Navbar code:

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-vira navbar-fixed-top">
           <div class="navigation-bar">
           <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                            <span class="sr-only">Zamknij nawigację</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <div class="logo">
                            <a href="#">XXXX</a>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right font-white">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">O mnie</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#ofert">Oferta</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Kontakt</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Comment: What does _not working_ mean? And refer to [Navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

Comment: Have you tried using the bootstrap class `hidden-xs`?...

Answer (score 0):

If you want the menu to be not shown on mobiles. you might consider using media queries and restrict its display

check the following snippet

```css
@media screen and (min-width:200px) and (max-width:500px){
  ul.nav{
    display:none;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-vira navbar-fixed-top">
           <div class="navigation-bar">
           <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                            <span class="sr-only">Zamknij nawigację</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <div class="logo">
                            <a href="#">XXXX</a>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right font-white">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">O mnie</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#ofert">Oferta</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Kontakt</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Hope it helps
PS:See the output  of full screen

Answer (score 0):

To add on to the other answer showing how to hide the nav completely,
the following HTML should allow the nav to work normally. You'll obviously need to add Bootstrap jQuery for the drop down functionality. I think the logo div was causing the issues.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-nav-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">XXXX</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-nav-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">O mnie</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#ofert">Oferta</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Kontakt</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```